# Self-contained hello-world program

Tags: code-golf, assembly, machine-code

I want a program that outputs "hello world" on console on my x86_64 based Linux computer. Yes, a complete program, not something silly that needs an interpreter or a compiler to work.

You may:

- use all glibc functionality
- submit a static executable
- submit a dynamic executable with dependencies if you outline them
- compile an ELF file
- dig into the ELF format and remove all unneeded stuff
- be creative and work around the ELF format

Describe here how you create and execute the program.

The shortest program wins.

Comment: Similar: http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

Comment: @PeterTaylor The page I immediately thought of when reading this. Thanks for digging it up before me.

Comment: [@breadbox](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4201/breadbox) is a high-rep user on our site. I'm sure they'll nail this one. ;-)

Comment: Too bad you specified the platform :)

Comment: @marinus why is this a bad thing?

Comment: marinus may use any platform he likes to go below the 45 bytes from http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

Comment: why not write your own platform? Thingy should fit into a bootsector :) 0x001d bytes: http://www.staerk.de/thorsten/How_to_program_your_own_OS plus two bytes boot sector signature

Comment: and sorry for calling this an OS, back in 2008 I was a bit ignorant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### MS-DOS .COM - 21 bytes

From the comments:

> marinus may use any platform he likes to go below the 45 bytes from muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html – Thorsten Staerk

So now I had to. (So don't accept this answer because it's cheating.)

He made a mistake, because that allows me to do:

```
BITS 16
              org     0x100
              mov     ah,9
              mov     dx,hello
              int     0x21
              int     0x20
hello:        db      "hello world$"
```

Compile with:

```
nasm -f bin -o hello.com hello.asm
```

And then DOSBOX or something will run the resulting `.com`, which is **21** bytes in size.

No hacks are even needed because `.com` files have no structure.

Comment: no mistake... I had it in my mind somewhere... I used to write programs with debug.exe... nopret.com, 2 bytes

Comment: that was why 70,000 bytes are not possible as .com program... and .com is not part of any URL ;)

Comment: the rules don't say that it has to terminate.  You can remove the int 0x20.

Comment: at the very least, the int 0x20 can be a ret.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you had in mind? Or you want any more hacky?

`EDITED(2)`

### Assembler (NASM) { source: 155 bytes, compiled: 384 bytes }

#### Source code: helloworld.nasm

```
global _start
_start:
write:
 mov eax, 4
 mov ebx, 1
 mov ecx, h
 mov edx, 12
 int 0x80
exit:
 mov eax, 1
 mov ebx, 0
 int 0x80
h: db 'hello world', 10, 0
```

#### Compile

```
$ nasm helloworld.nasm -f elf64 -o helloworld.o
$ ld helloworld.o -s -o helloworld
```

#### Execution

```
$ ./helloworld 
hello world
```

#### Size

```
$ ls -al helloworld.nasm helloworld
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 155 Jan  5 11:08 helloworld.nasm
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 384 Jan  5 11:09 helloworld
```

#### Platform:

```
$ uname -io
x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ nasm -v
NASM version 2.09.10 compiled on Oct 17 2011
```

Comment: use nasm as assembler and get it much smaller

Comment: ok, edited as `EDITED(2)`

Answer (score 1):

### Assembly - compiled: 76 bytes

This is a 32-bit executable, but taking advantage of backwards compatibility it will run on x86_64 systems too. At least it did on mine. It's based on [breadbox's "tiny.asm"](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) and it's hackier still so I wouldn't be that surprised if some Linuxes didn't want to touch it.

I tried it on Debian 7 in a VM, and it worked.

```
BITS 32
              org     0x00200000
              db      0x7F, "ELF"
hello:        db      "hello world", 10
              dw      2                               
              dw      3              
              ; nasm insisted on aligning them properly so let's do it this way                 
exit:         dd      0x80cd4066 ; inc eax - int 0x80 
              dd      start                          
              dd      phdr - $$                       
phdr:         dd      1                               
              dd      0                               
              dd      $$                              
              dw      1                               
              dw      0                               
              dd      filesize                        
              dd      filesize                        
start:        mov     ecx, hello ; B9 0400 0200 -> flag 1 set -> executable
              mov     edx, 12
              inc     eax
              shl     eax,2
              int     0x80
              xor     eax, eax
              jmp     exit
filesize      equ     $ - $$
```

It actually works:

```
~$ nasm -f bin -o hello hello.asm;chmod +x hello
~$ ./hello
hello world
~$ wc -c hello
76 hello
~$
```

It even neatly outputs a newline as I had a byte to spare in the ELF header.

Comment: Just tried it, works for me on an i7 running 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: [No output on tio](https://tio.run/##rVPBboMwDL3zFRaqtMOgC23Vba3UQ6VVmrTb9gMhSSFTIIykI93PMyCUqrBWWzUfMOT5mWfHDrGKy5JgDSuImRByjFXipNUD/C2EPAVfWuAIL0mcSAq3xh454zvrCwI@sWdluX5@e4XpxIETk3nUeGQQmqDaegE0hDbgfuOB@/SycZ0m46If4VpVhcwFdT0IBpkK6ydw2c7QphejltC0iKeKK80oyBSw4FHK0wh0zBLIcpmxXOxBSRBM3yigEriuQK6gwPuhDGa4Xhxl0EMfHhChMzSfV//kKQGGDfjVm26ggfqWpjTO9e9rbllZTPMq@Wh0jlYHDDUGf@zwobTraGfVXb7P4LoxuFLklgum@Bf7b1pzr90NJPKz8YwYr13SJawfAc0Qgnq/wF/BVuCoql4xXX8xw8hO41CwnoQuF61yBf29rSevQbHpISoWB8QbsnQ3xD3IyLyj/ZD1PcksXC2Fc9oV9rGzc9BM6jc)